# A origem de "primeiro de agosto primeiro de inverno" é do Brasil ou Portugal?

Tags: português-brasileiro, etimologia, expressões, português-europeu

A origem de "primeiro de agosto primeiro de inverno"
Do Brasil ou Portugal, visto agosto ser verão em Portugal

Comment: Aqui, um brasileiro carioca.  Nunca ouvi e nem sei o que significa.

Comment: Também nunca ouvi essa.

Comment: Deve ser Brasil, por causa do inverno. Mas sou do Rio Grande do Sul e nunca vi e nem ouvi

Comment: @Peixoto agora é que me enganaste bem. Diz no teu perfil Lisboa e afinal és de RS. (Eu por acaso pensava que esta expressão pudesse ser precisamente de perto do BR-RS, por causa da relativa proximidade dos Andes e da latitude ser muito a sul. Mas pronto, continua a expressão a ser um mistério.)

Comment: Eu sou gaúcho, mas moro em Lisboa há quase 2 anos...

Comment: @Peixoto, eu sempre ouvi isto em Portugal. E sempre me sugeriu o que o Artefacto diz abaixo. Imagino que no Rio Grande do Sul o inverno comece bem a sério já em junho ou julho, não?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ouve-se por vezes em Portugal. A ideia é que passa é a de que em Agosto os dias começam a ficar mais curtos (começando a arrefecer mais cedo) e o tempo a piorar. Na verdade, pelo menos na zona de Lisboa, as temperaturas médias do ar e da água só começam a descer na segunda metade de Agosto e a precipitação é semelhante em Julho e Agosto.

[Exemplo](https://cantinhodacasa.blogs.sapo.pt/primeiro-de-agosto-primeiro-de-inverno-1376942):

> Diz a minha amiga Mafalda: "Dentro de casa a ver televisão com noites quentes como esta, é tolice. Vamos aproveitar Julho, estas noites de verão, porque o primeiro dia de Agosto, é o primeiro dia de inverno".
>
> Comentei:" Ora agora que falas nisso, há dias, alguém disse isso mesmo, que o primeiro dia de Agosto é o primeiro dia de inverno".
>
> E continuou: " Claro que é. Os dias ficam mais pequenos, na praia temos as marés vivas, as nortadas,  as noites são frescas, o agasalho tem de andar connosco. Se Julho é o mês do verão, há que aproveitar as noites e sair para a rua".

Comment: Nos Estados Unidos, consideram que o dia do Trabalho (primeira segunda feira de setembro) marca o fim do verão nos estados do norte.  E marca bem, porque, como em Lisboa, os dias vão ficando cada vez mais curtos. Só que a temperatura cai muito mais.

Answer (score 1):

Este ditado conhece-se de sobremaneira no norte de Portugal e repete-se neste dia, 1/8.
Aponta ao facto de os dias reduzirem, esse encurtamento dura durante estes meses e o crescimento posterior dos dias nota se no fim de Dezembro e Janeiro posteriormente.
"A 20 de Janeiro quem vier conta uma hora e meia vai achar".
No dia 1/8 era comum, e algumas pessoas ainda seguem o rito tradicional e familiar, em jejum esfregar a teste com aguardente e beber o restante acreditando que se protegeriam contra maleitas do inverno e n/ ficariam assim doentes.
Cumprimentos :)

Answer (score 1):

É um ditado português que significa que o tempo do início de Agosto marca o que será o tempo no ínicio do Inverno.
Para mais contexto:
https://web.archive.org/web/20230802091201/https://regiaoriomaior.pt/1-de-agosto-1-de-inverno-com-super-luas/